# Battery draining within seconds

Tags: battery, battery-life

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II GT-I9105. My problem is battery draining. It works normally after I charge it to full, but as soon as the battery percentage hits 30%, draining accelerates and will go to zero within seconds (literally).

But if I charge it and unplug at 12%, it drains normally again...

What is the problem? Should I buy a new battery?

**Update:**  I have bought a new battery and recalibrated but the same battery draining occurs

Comment: Replace your battery !

Comment: @Droidzer, Sure its battery problem? I just wannna confirm before I replace.

Comment: I am sorry i just read your last lines. Can you tell me if do you use the same charger ?

Comment: Battery may need to be recalibrated.

Comment: @Droidzer... yes, I have been using the orginal cherger...

Comment: How would I recalibrate it?

Comment: @JacobThazhath Please see this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/how-do-i-recalibrate-the-battery-of-my-phone

Comment: Bought a new battery and recalibrated. Still no use.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your Android to factory setting and see if that helps. Otherwise I would suggest trying out a new ROM, as that helped improve my battery life considerably.