# Android Auto-Shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I own a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Lollipop 5.0.1) and have recently had the problem if it automatically shutting down whilst in mid-use. I would try turning it on again only for it to quickly shut itself down after the Samsung logo appears on the screen.

However, the problem goes away once I plug it into a power source and then turn it on.

Has anyone any experience on how to remedy this problem - if it is a application causing the auto shutdown or if it is due to something a little more sinister?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason of your Auto-shutdown could be low battery. (I know its "duh", but bear with me)

## Reason 1: Wrong Battery Stats:

This is most probably the problem, because some time ago, I was also in the same position as yours.
Here, you will see that your battery is well above 15%; yet it shutsdown in middle of it, and act asif the battery is finished (not booting there-after).

The thing is, that the battery *is* finished, but your phone is actually getting the wrong or messed up battery stats.
So when your battery is 1%, your phone is showing 20%.
And then **BOOM** your phone shutsdown unexpected to both user and the phone.

For me, In order to reset the battery stats, I have to pull out the battery and plug it in again, then with charger on, boot it and it will show correct battery stats.

**The culprit?**, well it was Easy Tether app.
I used it to connect to my PC and use the WiFi-internet on PC.
As I connected my phone to the PC, it was charging.
And Easy Tether, *somehow*, messed up my Battery Stats.

(I simply switched to PDAnet+ to get resolve it.)

**Solution:** You can re-calibrate your battery stats, by deleting the **batterystats.bin** system file (take precautions tho!).

UPDATE: @Arch gave a very good source about [Re-calibrating Battery Stats](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/how-do-i-recalibrate-the-battery-of-my-phone/29613#29613) Please take a look at it!

#### Reason 2: Damaged Battery.

Well, nothing can be done about this. Find a new battery and see if the problem persist.

---

If these dont work, try to be more specific about your circumstances.
You have hardly given any information you know.

Kudos!

Comment: This [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29613/109933) tell us that deleting that `batterystats.bin` file isn't necessary. I once incidentally also saw some users sharing the same view in comments but I don't remember where. May be some experienced users can help here.

Comment: Thnks @Arch that was very helpful!