# Related to Battery Charging

Tags: battery, charging

I noticed sometimes in my android device.

The battery status is about 10-15%. When I plug it with its charger, it changed instantly to 85-90%.  Later on, it goes to 60-65%.

My android device is 4.4.2 with root access.

How to diagnose and fix it?

Regards

EinfoMail

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/how-do-i-recalibrate-the-battery-of-my-phone

Comment: As per the link, battery calibration is required. Also I read, for battery calibration, root access is required. My device is rooted with Stock ROM. And battery is non-removable. In such case, will calibration work? If I use Battery Calibration Apk in non-rooted device, will it be functional?

Comment: Typically the battery calibration occurs when you do two cycles of 100% (or as high as it can go) to automatic shutdown. If you've done that and the behavior is what as described in your post, you could try a similar app (at your own risk), but honestly it may be your battery is at end of life and needs replacement.